# How do I attach a file to a file field when saving (update/insert) a node?

Tags: 7, entities, files

After creating programmatically a PDF file with [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/), I am trying to attach it to my field "file_fichier", here is what my code looks like

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave().
 */
function hook_node_presave($node) {

  if($node->type=='profil'){

    $uri = 'public://profiles/fichier';
    $filename = $node->title.' - PDF - '.$node->language.'.pdf';
    $file_path = $uri . '/' . $filename;

    // Output PDF with TCPDF
    $pdf->Output($file_path, 'F');

    $file = new stdClass;
    $file->uid = $node->uid;
    $file->filename = pathinfo($file_path, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
    $file->uri = $file_path;
    $file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($file_path);
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    file_save($file);

    dpm($file);

    // Now attach file to the file field.
    $node->field_fichier[$node->language][] = (array) $file;

  }

}
```

The PDF file is well saved to `public://profiles/fichier/file_name.pdf` as expected, and it's also recorded to the 'file_managed' table.

But the problem is that it's not attached to the field `field_fichier`, and nothing seems to happen to the `field_data_field_fichier` table

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer, I finally avoided to link the pdf with my node field. I simply saved it during node add/edit process into a specific directory. Then I loaded it directly into theme file. I checked your solution but didn't find the time to test it. I think my $file object had already an fid after file_save() was triggered.

Comment: If you post your solution is better for other users that can have in the future the same problem, and you can check your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you don't have the fid.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave().
 */
function hook_node_presave($node) {

  if($node->type=='profil'){

    $uri = 'public://profiles/fichier';
    $filename = $node->title.' - PDF - '.$node->language.'.pdf';
    $file_path = $uri . '/' . $filename;

    // Output PDF with TCPDF
    $pdf->Output($file_path, 'F');

    $file_temp = file_get_contents($file_path);

    // Saves a file to the specified destination and creates a database entry.
    $file_temp = file_save_data($file_temp, $file_path, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);

   $node->field_fichier = array(
     'und' => array(
       0 => array(
        'fid' => $file_temp->fid,
        'filename' => $file_temp->filename,
        'filemime' => $file_temp->filemime,
        'uid' => $node->uid;,
        'uri' => $file_temp->uri,
        'status' => 1,
        'display' => 1
    )
  )
);
```